# Extjs virtual keyboard

Tags: keyboard, extjs3

I am using ExtJs virtual keyboard

Ref: 
http://efattal.fr/extjs-dev/examples/virtualkeyboard

I want to fire an ajax request on press of "enter" key of the virtual keyboard.
Is there any way to  capture the "Enter" key press event ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was facing same problem. try dis
`listeners: {
                           keypress: function(keyboard, keyValue){
                               if(typeof console != 'undefined')
                                   console.log(keyValue);
                               if(keyValue=="\n")
                               {  //your code here }
                            }
             }`